# How do I get the value of a checkbox in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, aura-iteration

I have a 2 date field where user can enter 2 dates and I iterate between the 2 dates. each date will bring a checkbox of am or pm. I wanna get the value of each date and if either checkbox was checked for that date or no when I hit a save button. for example I want the value be like on 09/18/2017 am checkbox been checked. thanks

[image]

```
Component
      <div style="{!v.showBigTable}">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box_small " style="width: 15%;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>AM</th>
                    <th>PM</th>
                </tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.dateGenerater}" var="wrap">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- <output size="15" type="String" value="{!v.dateName}" /> -->
                            <output size="25" type="Date" value="{!wrap}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="amCheckBox" value="" change="{!c.updateCheckboxes}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="pmCheckBox" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new component specifically for this purpose like below.Lets call is AMPMPicker

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute type="boolean" default="false" name="isAM"/>
  <td>
     <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="amCheckBox" value="" change="{!c.updateCheckboxes}" />
   </td>
   <td>
      <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="pmCheckBox" value="" {!c.updateCheckboxes}"/>
    </td>
 </aura:component>
```

The JS Controller will be as below

```
({
   updateCheckboxes: function(cmp, evt) {
     var amCmp = cmp.find("amCheckBox").get("v.value");
     var pmCmp = cmp.find("pmCheckBox").get("v.value");
     if(amCmp){
         cmp.get("v.isAM",true) ;
     }
     else if(pmCmp){
         cmp.get("v.isAM",false) ;
      }
   }
})
```

Now Modify your parent component as below

```
<div style="{!v.showBigTable}">
    <div class="slds-box slds-box_small " style="width: 15%;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>AM</th>
                <th>PM</th>
            </tr>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.dateGenerater}" var="wrap">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <output size="15" type="String" value="{!v.dateName}" /> -->
                        <output size="25" type="Date" value="{!wrap}" />
                    </td>
                    <c:AMPMPicker isAM="{!wrap.isAM}"/>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create a variable in your dateGenerater array Object to hold the boolean value .

Comment: OP had already posted the question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192609/get-the-value-of-the-checkbox) and flagged as off topic since it showed little to no research effort.